# Batch programming a runas utility creater

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

I'm attempting to write a batch file that makes it easier for me to make runas utility shortcuts on a computers desktop.

I have this mostly done, I have all the variables generated, I'm just having issues with the actual shortcut creation part of the script.

This is the code I am using to create the shortcut. With this code, I am using for variables: `%shortcutName%` as `Internet Explorer`, `%computername%` is my computers name, which doesn't include any special characters or spaces, %user% is a local user account which is an administrator (Again no special characters or spaces), and `%UserInputpath%` is equal to `"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"` (When you drag and drop a file into the command prompt window it generates this link, and wraps it in quotes if needed)

```
powershell "$s=(New-Object -COM WScript.Shell).CreateShortcut('%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\%shortcutName%.lnk');$s.TargetPath='runas /user:%computername%\%user% /savecred %UserInputPath%';$s.Save()"
```

I think that my problem stems from the quotes as I said earlier, but I'm not really sure how to handle the issue.

This is the error that I get:

```
Value does not fall within the expected range.
At line:1 char:98
+ ... lorer.lnk');$s.TargetPath='runas /user:iamgroot\admin /savecred C ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException

Unable to save shortcut "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Internet Explorer.lnk".
At line:1 char:203
+ ...  /savecred C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe';$s.Save()
+                                                                 ~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], DirectoryNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException
```

Comment: You should probably do this as a pure PowerShell script; the way quotes are used in batch and in PowerShell can create some odd conflicts, and you may be running into that. Normally, strings in PowerShell do not get expanded if quoted with `'`, and if you want to reference an environment variable within PowerShell, it's `$env:variablename` rather than the batch `%variablename%`.

Comment: Taking a step back -- `%user%` may be an administrator, but if UAC is enabled, runas.exe will log on `%user%` as a standard user. Is that your intention?

Comment: @eryksun I'm not switching users, I'm making a shortcut that runs the file as another user

Comment: Yes, runas.exe logs the target user on to get an access token to call `CreateProcessAsUser`. You noted that `%user%` is an administrator, but nowadays with UAC this user will be logged on with a split token (one  that's basically standard, and one that's elevated). runas.exe will use the standard token that's stripped of privileges, has the administrators group disabled for everything except deny access, and has only medium instead of high integrity level.

Comment: As to your shortcut, `TargetPath` should only have the fully-qualified path to runas.exe, e.g. `'%SystemRoot%\System32\runas.exe'`. The command-line arguments get stored in the [`Arguments`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yf7kaky2(v=vs.84).aspx) property.

Comment: @eryksun I'm confused, because I'm not trying to run runas.exe as another user, I want to run another program as another user. It is possible that I am completely misunderstanding you

Comment: The shortcut will run the target program with the access token of another user, which requires logging that user on to actually create the token. My point was that, if UAC is enabled, this token won't actually have administrator privileges unless it's the one and only machine "Administrator" account (RID 500) and also that the Administrator account has been excepted from UAC by local policy.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is you wrap your script with this...

```
#Run as Adminstrator

If (-NOT ([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal][Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] "Administrator"))

{   
$arguments = "& '" + $myinvocation.mycommand.definition + "'"
Start-Process powershell -Verb runAs -ArgumentList $arguments

%Your Coder HERE%

}
```

This little section of code resolved all my not administrator errors.

Let me know how it works out for you,

The UnderDog

Comment: I was trying to avoid having the user have to log in as an administrator to open certain programs.