# How to QUIETLY start Powershell.exe using different credentials (without getting prompted for username/password)?

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

I've spent more time on this that I'd like to admit.  I'm looking for powershell code that will ***quietly*** start a new PowerShell instance (in the existing PowerShell Window) using different credentials.

The best I can come up with is extremely clunky... popping up two different Powershell Windows on my screen before finally giving me a prompt.  Apparently, the -NoNewWindow argument doesn't prevent the opening of any new PowerShell windows.

**My VERY clunky code:**

```
Start-Process powershell.exe -Credential $DomainAdmin -WorkingDirectory $env:windir -NoNewWindow -ArgumentList "Start-Process powershell.exe -Verb runAs"
```

If there is a way to "Runas" Powershell.exe from a desktop shortcut (and saving the username/password).  I'd also be happy with that.  Below, is the code I attempted to make.  However, there seems to be a bug that keeps giving me the error, "267: The directory name is invalid"

**Batch file that doesn't work:**

```
runas.exe /savecred /env /noprofile /user:MKA "powershell.exe -noprofile -command \"start-process -WorkingDirectory c:\temp powershell -verb RunAs\""
```

A solution would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't think Runas works the way you think it does. if UAC is enabled, `runas.exe` will log on `%user%` as a standard user, not as an administrator. I'm not sure if what you are trying to do is possible, as I posted a very similar question recently and was not able to get an answer that worked. [Link to my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43939765/batch-programming-a-runas-utility-creater)

Comment: My question would have to be why do you want to do open a new session? If it's for remote connections into a new system then you can run that in the same powershell window and call each session you make as needed in your script.

Comment: No remoting.  I actually mean an instance of Powershell.  Similar to just typing, "Powershell" while in a powershell console window... except with a different user context.

Comment: In your "very clunky code", why are you invoking 2 new powershell windows?  You are with the initial Start-Process (which would actually supress a new popup) and then in the argument list, you call another Start-Process powershell.exe which will pop up the window...

Comment: The initial start-process with the -noprofile command still opens an extra Powershell window; plus, the spawned PS window isn't interactive.  It wont respond to keyboard or mouse.   I can only close the Window.

Comment: What you are describing is [`psexec.exe`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) but saving a password in a desktop shortcut would be a terrible security practice.

Comment: What is the purpose/goal?

Comment: The runas.exe example works fine for me in Windows 10. If you're using an account that's excluded from UAC restrictions (e.g. Administrator), then the `start-process` command doesn't need `-Verb RunAs` and `-NoNewWindow` can be added. If the account needs elevation, you may as well remove the `-WorkingDirectory` option because the Application Information service will ignore this request and start the process in `%SystemRoot%\System32`.

Comment: In the first command, `-NoNewWindow` is ignored because it calls [`CreateProcessWithLogonW`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682431), which requests the Secondary Logon service to logon the user and create the process via `CreateProcessAsUser`. runas.exe aslo calls `CreateProcessWithLogonW`. It's documented that this function always uses the creation flag `CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE`, and it's also documented that [`CREATE_NO_WINDOW`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684863#CREATE_NO_WINDOW) is ignored in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run as user `MKA`, create a shortcut with this in `Target` window:

```
C:\Windows\System32\runas.exe /User:MKA /savecred C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
```

To hide a PowerShell console window, you can put this code at the top of the script being executed. which is my favoured solution in [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1802127/how-to-run-a-powershell-script-without-displaying-a-window/27992426#27992426).

```
add-type -name win -member '[DllImport("user32.dll")] public static extern bool ShowWindow(int handle, int state);' -namespace native
[native.win]::ShowWindow(([System.Diagnostics.Process]::GetCurrentProcess() | Get-Process).MainWindowHandle, 0)
```

[The post discusses other ways that may be more suitable for you.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1802127/how-to-run-a-powershell-script-without-displaying-a-window)